# WebSocket client failing to handshake

Tags: c#, html, websocket

I've recently started playing around with HTML5 WebSockets, and I've got a simple jQuery web client and a console application server.  After reading up on the hand shaking here's what I currently have for the client:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:100", ["chat"]);
socket.onopen = function() {
    console.log(socket.readyState);
}
```

This sends the following to my server:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 127.0.0.1:100
Origin: http://localhost:57944
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dBQ0epP7wmgHDEJc6Me95Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
```

Now, my server code.

First off, I read through the lines sent above from the client, and find the `Sec-WebSocket-Key` value and save this to my variable `key`.

Then I append the *magic number* from the [Wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) which is **258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11**. This results in the following code:

```
key = string.Concat(key, "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");
using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
{
    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    responseKey = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

Finally, my response key is used in the construction of the message I send back to the client, which is:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: u9guLPph1FeCPuOpFNs4F1b+UqY=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
[blank line, as requested in spec]
```

However, my `socket.readyState` goes from 0 to 3 and then fails with the following error `WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:100/' failed:`.

I've read that this could be down to my server using an incompatible protocol to the client, but I'm not entirely sure on where to start looking if this is the case. If not, does anyone have any idea how to fix this or where I can go for more information as I'm a little stumped.

**21st March 2013**

After reading @djc's comment below, I modified my server code to send back the acknowledgement with the following:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    sw.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";

    // get response and calculate responseKey here (getting bytes as UTF-8 from client)

    sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake");
    sw.WriteLine("Upgrade: websocket");
    sw.WriteLine("Connection: Upgrade");
    sw.WriteLine("WebSocket-Origin: http://localhost:57944");
    sw.WriteLine("WebSocket-Location: 127.0.0.1:100");
    sw.WriteLine("Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + responseKey);
    sw.WriteLine("");
    sw.Flush();
}
```

Well, I no longer get an error on the client - but the 'socket.readyState' remains at 0 and my `socket.onopen` block is never fired - although I see the client connection attempt coming through.

Comment: Have you tried without setting the protocol? (I.e. leaving off the chat bit.)

Comment: @djc unfortunately for me, yes. I had it without the chat bit before trying with, same error.

Comment: Maybe you should fill in the response key, so I can check it with my own code. (Or another pair of matching Sec-WebSocket-Key and Sec-WebSocket-Accept values.)

Comment: @djc done, I've ran it again and amended the client request and the calculated by server.

Comment: Okay, my code matches yours. Does your response end with two sets of \r\n?

Comment: @djc I've tried with the default `StreamWriter.NewLine` of \r\n and also changed it to \r\n\r\n but no dice. I've also tried with the `Encoding` on UTF-8 and ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) I finally managed to get it working. Here's my client code:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8181/websession", ['chat','superchat']);
            
socket.onopen = function()
{
    $("div#messages").append("<p class=\"event\">Socket is connected.</p>");
    socket.send("Thanks!");
};
```

Seems the inclusion of `websession` for cookie management and `['chat','superchat']` protocols were required.

The server:

```
using (TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != string.Empty)
    {
        string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && tokens.Length > 1)
        {
            headers[tokens[0]] = tokens[1].Trim();
        }
    }

    string responseKey = "";
    string key = string.Concat(headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key"], "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");
    using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
    {
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        responseKey = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols");
    sw.WriteLine("Upgrade: websocket");
    sw.WriteLine("Connection: Upgrade");
    sw.WriteLine("Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + responseKey);
    sw.WriteLine("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat");
    sw.WriteLine("");
    sw.Flush();
}
```

Now I'm getting a valid connection, but can't send / receive data with the server - but that's another story I guess.

Comment: Nice work, I actually figured out you do not require to include those chat and superchat protocols, you just need to add extra 1 more line at the end of response.

Comment: @EnglishMaster you're exactly right, the inclusion of the protocols was a red herring, obviously what I was missing was a very important `\r\n\r\n` to signify the end of the transmission.